# Django: related_name vs Queryset Performance?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model with a ForeignKey to another model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="foo", unique=True)
```

However, I don't really like needing to call `user.foo.all().first()`, because this is going to exclusively be a unique one-to-one. So I've decided to do this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def foo(self):
        foo, created = Foo.objects.get_or_create(...)
```

So I can just return `user.foo`. Is there any benefit to using the reverse relationship?

Comment: If it is a one to one relationship why don't you use [one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)?

Comment: @KlausD. thanks for pointing me at this.